# ms graph upload session stream and response drive item

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

**Requirement:** upload a large file (4MB+) using MSGraph (onedrive or Sharepoint) and return its corresponding DriveID (i.e. DriveItem)

This example uses PHP but I assume it's common due to the endpoint response.

**Prerequisites:**

- MS Registered App with correct permissions
- Valid auth token

**Overview of large file uploads:** 2 calls at a minimum required.

1. Create Upload Session Request
2. Use Session to upload chuncks of data

Using the PHP sdk https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php

From point 1 our response is \Microsoft\Graph\Model\UploadSession

From point 2 (within a loop while chuncks < filesize) response is also \Microsoft\Graph\Model\UploadSession but with some additional information

Once the upload completes these are the results that come out of the UploadSession Object

```
    object(Microsoft\Graph\Model\UploadSession)#274 (1) {
  ["_propDict":protected]=>
  array(16) {
    ["@odata.context"]=>
    string(79) "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/EH_SHARED/_api/v2.0/$metadata#items/$entity"
    ["@content.downloadUrl"]=>
    string(1692) "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/EH_SHARED/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=6b41a4a1-bb7c-4abb-991a-8ff743ea7271&T... zlJTjdQcktWR2I2Y0JRWFlFaDVmVi9tUklIVT0&ApiVersion=2.0"
    ["createdBy"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["application"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "17ea34aa-...-786eb4146c"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(12) "Test App"
      }
      ["user"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["email"]=>
        string(36) "adminin...microsoft.com"
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "baaeb-...-1ce24ca191"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(13) "DN"
      }
    }
    ["createdDateTime"]=>
    string(20) "2022-04-22T03:44:49Z"
    ["eTag"]=>
    string(42) ""{6B41A4A1-...-43EA7271},4""
    ["id"]=>
    string(34) "01IX5T2WN'..'JSGUP65B6U4TR"
    ["lastModifiedBy"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["application"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "17eaa...-9eb4146c"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(12) "Test App"
      }
      ["user"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["email"]=>
        string(36) "admin1@microsoft.com"
        ["id"]=>
        string(36) "baaeb-...-ce24ca191"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(13) "DN"
      }
    }
    ["lastModifiedDateTime"]=>
    string(20) "2022-04-22T03:44:50Z"
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "Firewall-1.png"
    ["parentReference"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["driveType"]=>
      string(15) "documentLibrary"
      ["driveId"]=>
      string(66) "b!LH33a_4...PHrdpRILuxk1T-EvS"
      ["id"]=>
      string(34) "01IX5T2....F5YQ4CK7WGZC"
      ["path"]=>
      string(127) "/drives/b!LH33a_4wiEu0A4FKQ6j...MEu_PHrdpRILuxk1T-EvS/root:/Clients/CompanyA/JN00001 - Test Project/images"
    }
    ["webUrl"]=>
    string(132) "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/EH_SHARED/TEST%20Files/Clients/CompanyA/JN00001%20-%20Test%20Project/images/Firewall-1.png"
    ["cTag"]=>
    string(44) ""c:{6B41A-....-43EA7271},4""
    ["file"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["hashes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["quickXorHash"]=>
        string(28) "uI9XNv6......s3e5/rHic="
      }
      ["irmEnabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["mimeType"]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
    }
    ["fileSystemInfo"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["createdDateTime"]=>
      string(20) "2022-04-22T03:44:49Z"
      ["lastModifiedDateTime"]=>
      string(20) "2022-04-22T03:44:50Z"
    }
    ["image"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["size"]=>
    int(27721)
  }
}
```

The only part of this that references the newly uploaded document is the 'webUrl'

```
$response->getProperties()

["webUrl"]=>
    string(132) "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/EH_SHARED/TEST%20Files/Clients/CompanyA/JN00001%20-%20Test%20Project/images/Firewall-1.png"
```

So, with the above information **how can one retrieve the DriveID of the file that has just been uploaded**? I've tried use MSGraph API as a get request on the webURL which returns a "401 Unauthorized" error.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Return type of Graph call must be of \Microsoft\Graph\Model\DriveItem

```
$returnType = \Microsoft\Graph\Model\DriveItem::class;
$result = $graph->createRequest("PUT", $graph_url)
                ->addHeaders($headers)
                ->attachBody($data)
                ->setReturnType($returnType)
                ->setTimeout("1000")
                ->execute();
```

This will return the DriveItem and allow the retrieval of DriveId.
NOTE: I've continued to use

```
$returnType = \Microsoft\Graph\Model\UploadSession::class;
```

and only switched to DriveItem on the last loop ($bytes = $chuncksize)
Now just to catch a curl upload error when uploading large files.... another post likely

Comment: NOTE: cURL upload error is likely a result of an unstable network connection. TBC once a fixed line is installed in a few days.